# CSS blur filter not working in Firefox and IE 10, any alternatives?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, blur

I'm using this CSS code for `blur` effect:

```
.blur{
-webkit-filter : blur(5px);
-moz-filter    : blur(5px);
-o-filter      : blur(5px);
-ms-filter     : blur(5px);
filter         : blur(5px);
opacity        : 0.4      ;
}
```

and the `blur` is working fine in Chrome, but nothing happens in Firefox or IE 10.

I also tried this example http://jsbin.com/ulufot/31/edit but for IE 10, none worked.

I need some advice at this moment, because I'm runing out of ideas...

Comment: I think Firefox still doesn't support CSS3 filters I'm afraid :(

Comment: for FF I could use svg-based filter (see the link in my question). but I still don't have a working solution for IE.

Comment: IE10 also supports SVG filters - but not for non-SVG content

Comment: Firefox35+ supports blur attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS3 filters are not supported in IE10 or Firefox (v.23), and support is unknown for those browsers in the near future.

Have a look: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

You could use Modernizr to check for CSS filter support and fallback to a background image if not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use svg filters but you cant animate them atm on firefox and ie10.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur

Comment: You can use a blur combined with a pseudo-element with background of it's parent using `-moz-element` and the SVG filter to fake a fading blur.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd share my solution to this issue. My low-tech solution is to force load the img at very low resolution i.e. width=20px and then stretch the image to fit the inside of a div. IE will stretch the image and blur the image.